# Alamofire 5.0.0-beta3 -> Timeout

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

With `Alamofire 5`, requests can be done using `AF.request(:)` functions where I cannot find a way to set `timeoutInterval`, unless I'm using

```
AF.request(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible)
```

I know, it's possible to set `timeoutInterval` to `urlRequest` passed to `Alamofire`, but what if I'm using functions with `URLConvertibles`:

```
public static func request(_ url: URLConvertible, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, headers: Alamofire.HTTPHeaders? = nil, interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil) -> Alamofire.DataRequest
// or
public static func request<Parameters>(_ url: URLConvertible, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil, encoder: ParameterEncoder = URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default, headers: Alamofire.HTTPHeaders? = nil, interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil) -> Alamofire.DataRequest where Parameters : Encodable
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to set a timeout when you pass individual `URLRequest` components, as Alamofire's top-levels don't (and will never) cover the entire range of `URLRequest` parameters. Instead, it's best to adopt `URLRequestConvertible` for your request types, whether separate values or one router.

Additionally, you can always create your own top level API that does take all of the parameters you care about and encapsulates them into a `URLRequestConvertible` value.

Comment: I think I've got your point when telling to-level request types. Anyway, my question is, how can we set timeout when we use AF functions with AF.URLConvertible's, as they've more options (Parameters, Decodables)?

Comment: You can't set a timeout when you're passing the components of a `URLRequest`.

Comment: Could you clarify? URLRequest has its own timeoutInterval parameter and can be casted to URLRequestConvertible. Btw, I've tested timeout interval of URLRequest passed to Alamofire and its working.